# How to do a specific lambda expression in normal Java Android

Tags: java, android, lambda

I am currently using a library, which uses a lambda expression to get the color. I tried to look into lambda, but I can't seem to understand it, or how to adapt the code.

The libary I am using is called [Aesthetic](https://github.com/afollestad/aesthetic) and this is the code:

```
Aesthetic.get()
    .colorPrimary()
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(color -> {
        System.out.println("The color is " + color);
    });
```

How can I get the color without using `->`, as I don't want to use Java 1.8 in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `subscribe` method takes a `Consumer<Integer>`. The lambda is basically representing an instance of that. Therefore, you just need to create an instance of `Consumer<Integer>`. You can do this using anonymous classes:

```
.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(Integer color) {
            System.out.println("The color is " + color);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Even though it seems like a bad question, you helped me solve something I've been fiddling with for the past 4 days!